# Changing the F# tools Visual Studio 2010 uses

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, f#, intellisense, fsc

I rebuilt F# with few syntax additions. I was able to tell VS2010 to use them for F# Interactive and for building, but the code editor still claims I'm making errors (even though the project builds just fine).

Is it even possible to change this? If it is - how?

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, there is no way to change the IntelliSense service used by F# in Visual Studio. The Visual Studio component isn't a part of the open-source release and it has a reference to strongly-signed `FSharp.Compiler.dll`. I'm not sure if there is some way to trick .NET to load a different assembly instead (specifying `bindingRedirect` in `app.config` requires the same strong name). If you find some way, let me know :-) I'd like to use it with [my modified  version of F#](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-variations-joinads.aspx) too.

If you want to get some IntelliSense for your modified F#, you can use the [F# MonoDevelop plugin](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-in-monodevelop.aspx). The plugin is open-source and you can change the F# version used in the `Services/FSharpCompiler.fs` file (see [the source on GitHub](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/blob/master/src/Services/FSharpCompiler.fs)).

Comment: Weird, I upvoted you saw a unicorn kiss into an exploding heart.

Comment: @Stephen: the unicorn seems to be new. Seen it in several cases. Weird.

@Tomas: I'll try few more ideas I have, hopefully one of them will work. I like my Visual Studio and prefer not to switch over to MonoDevelop.

Comment: @Stephen, @Ramon, the date, the date... look at the date :)